# Remove Button Shadow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working in Bootstrap 3 and trying to remove the shadow/outline of my buttons. The code I have currently does this partially. The outline still appears for a split-second when the button is clicked.

Here is a link to my [codepen](http://codepen.io/Hudson_Taylor11/pen/grVJLj).

```css
 .btn:active,
 .btn:focus,
 .btn.active {
   background-image: none;
   outline: 0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### UPDATE - Boostrap 4

In this version you can remove the button shadow by using utility class `shadow-none`.

```css
.btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <button class="btn shadow-none">No Shadow</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <button class="btn shadow-sm">Shadow Small</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <button class="btn shadow">Regular Shadow</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <button class="btn shadow-lg">Shadow Large</button>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

See more info [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/shadows/)

---

#### OLD  Answer - Bootstrap 3

You were missing this:

```css
.btn.active.focus, .btn.active:focus, .btn.focus, .btn.focus:active, .btn:active:focus, .btn:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

So you need to reset it. (`!important` only used for demo - DO NOT USE in your development code)

Snippet

```css
.container-fluid {
  text-align: center;
}
body .btn {
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
}
.btn.active.focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn.focus:active,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
  outline-offset: 0  !important;
  background-image: none  !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none  !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <p>result</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button class="btn">Rock</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button class="btn">Paper</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button class="btn">Scissors</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

[Bootstrap 4.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.0/scss/utilities/_shadows.scss#L6) supports adding a class `shadow-none` to remove a shadow.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<p>Click both buttons below to see the difference:</p>
<button class="btn">Bootstrap button</button>
<button class="btn shadow-none">Bootstrap (4.1) button without shadow</button>
```

Comment: `shadow-none` has no **!important** attribute so that sometimes not work.

Comment: It actually does have an !important rule, have look at the [source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.0/scss/utilities/_shadows.scss#L6)

Comment: `shadow-none` may not be the best solution as it doesn't allow for keyboard accessibility. of course if that doesn't matter to you, then it does work in removing that pesky shadow.

Answer (score 9):

**bootstrap 4**

in my case it was enough:

```
.btn:focus{
box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your selector for this

```
.btn:active,
.btn:focus,
.btn.active,
.btn:active:focus {
   background-image: none;
   outline: 0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this style will help

```
.btn:active:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this snippet, It will be fixed.

```
    .btn:active,
.btn:focus,
.btn.active {
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
   outline: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-link currency-selector">Submit</button>
.currency-selector {
text-decoration: none !important;
}
.currency-selector:hover {
 text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: We can use btn-link and can add a class later we can modify it. it worked

Comment: Please, add some context like what is this code and how to use it and what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

## Add *shadow-none* class using jquery

***shadow-none*** class is used to remove shadow in bootstrap.
Also it can be simplified by adding this class using little jquery code. So you don't have to add this class to each button saperatly.
So before using this solution you have to add [jquery cdn](https://releases.jquery.com).
Choose minified version and copy it to your html page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    {
        $(".btn").addClass("shadow-none");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```